# Ordenar un List de Objetos en Java

Tags: java, string, lista, ordenamiento, poo

Dispongo de una lista de objetos java propios, los cuales necesitan ser ordenados por la propiedad código de el propio objeto.

```
    List<Calle> listaDeCalles;
    Calle calle1 = new Calle();
    calle1.setCodigo("A4");
...

    listaDeCalles.add(calle1);
    listaDeCalles.add(calle2);
    listaDeCalles.add(calle3);
```

Existe alguna forma de hacerlo?

Se que existe la opción de hacerlo con el `Collections.sort`:

```
 java.util.Collections.sort(listaDeCalles)
```

Y de hacerlo con un Set:

```
Set<Calle> setDeCalles = new Set<Calle>();
```

Pero ninguna de las dos es viable debido a que algunos métodos como el `equals` y el `compareTo` han sido sobrescritos previamente. Y además la idea esta en que no toque PARA NADA la clase Calle ni su clase padre.

Lo que seria ideal para este caso seria que existiera un método el cual ordene una lista por la propiedad código la cual es un `String` de forma ascendente o descendente.

Answer (score 9):

Tu mejor opción es implementar un `Comparator` (anónimo o no) e incluirlo en la función `Collections.sort`

```
//Expresión lambda java8
Collections.sort(listaCalles, (o1, o2) -> o1.getCodigo().compareTo(o2.getCodigo()));

//Clase anónima
Collections.sort(listaCalles, new Comparator<Calle>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Calle o1, Calle o2) {
        return o1.getCodigo().compareTo(o2.getCodigo());
    }
});
```

He usado `compareTo()` como función de comparación de ejemplo...

Para un comparador parametrizable te dejo este código

```
class CalleComparatorByCodigo implements Comparator<Calle> {
    private boolean asc;
    CalleComparatorByCodigo(boolean asc) {
        this.asc = asc;
    }
    @Override
    public int compare(Calle o1, Calle o2) {
        int ret;
        if (asc) {
            ret = o1.getCodigo().compareTo(o2.getCodigo());
        } else {
            ret = o2.getCodigo().compareTo(o1.getCodigo());
        }
        return ret;
    }
}
```

Puedes usarlo así:

```
Collections.sort(listaCalles, new CalleComparatorByCodigo(true));
```

**EDIT:** Edito para añadir otra funcionalidad de Java8 que he aprendido recientemente y que puede resultar también útil para estos casos

```
listaCalles.sort(Comparator.comparing(Calle::getCodigo));
```

O en sentido inverso

```
listaCalles.sort(Comparator.comparing(Calle::getCodigo).reversed());
```

Otro regalo de Java8 para sus fieles.

Comment: Agradezco la respuesta, seria buena en caso de que pudiera crear nuevas clases o modificar la misma, ya que como dije no puedo. Seguiré esperando una respuesta que se adapte mas a mis necesidades. Gracias!

Comment: @Ralsho En realidad, el uso de una clase anónima se ajustaría a tus restricciones. Simplemente tendrías que invertir el valor de retorno del `compare` de acuerdo a tus necesidades de hacer la ordenación ascendente o descendente en cada ordenación que invoques. Esta solución no utiliza ni el `equals` ni el `compareTo` de la clase `Calle`. Por otro lado, no sabía que no podías crear clases nuevas...